# How can I install and use text-to-speech software?

Tags: installation, software-recommendation, sound, text-to-speech

I want to convert text to an audio file containing synthesised speech that reads out that text. What free (libre+gratis) software is available for this and how do I install and use it?

I don't need to use it as an accessibility tool - I just want to be able to listen back to my revision notes while doing other things, like playing games.