# TTS in multiple languages, to MP3

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, text-to-speech

I'm looking for a software that can read different languages in the same text.
I would prefer a software for ubuntu, but I can accept to use wine.

The document in question has a series of sentences in English + the Spanish equivalent.
My idea was to create a MP3 file of the recording of these sentences, so that I could listen it to practice my pronunciation.

Suggestions on how I can carry out this project are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

[Google Translator](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=wT#en/es/I'm%20looking%20for%20a%20software%20that%20can%20read%20different%20languages%20in%20the%20same%20text.%20I%20would%20prefer%20a%20software%20for%20ubuntu%2C%20but%20I%20can%20accept%20to%20use%20wine.%0A%0AThe%20document%20in%20question%20has%20a%20series%20of%20sentences%20in%20English%20%2B%20the%20Spanish%20equivalent.%20My%20idea%20was%20to%20create%20a%20MP3%20file%20of%20the%20recording%20of%20these%20sentences%2C%20so%20that%20I%20could%20listen%20it%20to%20practice%20my%20pronunciation.%0A%0ASuggestions%20on%20how%20I%20can%20carry%20out%20this%20project%20are%20welcome!) can read different languages very good. Just click the listen button.

Now, there is a simple small utility that can record to mp3 anything which plays through your speakers, and therefore from your web browser, called [Audio Recorder](https://launchpad.net/audio-recorder):

[image: Audio Recorder]

To install it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:osmoma/audio-recorder
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install audio-recorder
```

<sup>Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/audio-recorder-for-linux-easily-record-audio-streams-to-mp3</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with the command line, then [Festival](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/festival/) which you can install from Ubuntu Software Centre is a speech synthesis system. You will also need to install a Spanish voice (`sudo apt-get install festvox-ellpc11k`). Once there, you can have Festival read text like this:

```
echo "Hi there" | festival --tts
echo "Buenos dias" | festival --tts --language spanish
```

You may also want to investigate the `text2wave` command, installed with Festival, which saves the spoken words as a WAV file rather than speaking them directly; you can then use that WAV file for practice, or convert it to an MP3 if you prefer (using a tool such as `lame`.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120223/349837) [**gTTS**](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/) does exactly that on CLI:

```
sudo -H pip install gTTS  # Install
```

Usage

```
gtts-cli 'hello' --output hello.mp3
gtts-cli --slow "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that" | play -t mp3 -
gtts-cli -l es "Seamos realistas y hagamos lo imposible" | play -t mp3 -
gtts-cli -l fr 'Liberté, égalité, fraternité' | play -t mp3 -
```

Google undocumented API [doesn't seem to offer different voices](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/109).