# How can I add text-to-speech to GoldenDict?

Tags: dictionary, goldendict

How can I add a text to speech service or any other similar services to GoldenDict for offline use?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and I want to learn how to pronounce English words I don't know.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the *Programs* tab to plug a text to speech software ([**espeak**](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) for example) into the GoldenDict.

Here are the steps:

1. Install *espeak*:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install espeak
   ```
2. Open GoldenDict and hit <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the **Dictionaries** window (or select *Edit/Dictionaries* menu).
3. On the **Sources** tab, select **Programs** tab.
4. Click the **Add** button, select **Audio** for the *Type* column, enter **espeak** for the *Name*, and `espeak -v en %GDWORD%` for the *Command Line* column.
5. Don't forget to check the *Enabled* box.
6. Click OK
7. Close the GoldenDict window and reopen it.

Now you have an item named **espeak** in your dictionaries and your translation results. Clicking the speaker icon in front of the word in **espeak** result, reads the word for you.

Comment: most people want to use `en-us` after -v so my command is `espeak -v en-us %GDWORD%` to use the American accent. if you want more options such as speed, etc. `espeak --help` tell every thing.

Comment: IMO, it is worth to mention that for icon column you can use its original logo located at `/usr/share/doc/espeak/docs/images/lips.png` in Debian-based systems.

Answer (score 6):

Recent versions of GoldenDict have a *Programs* tab in the settings menu where you can add custom commands to be run on your search term.

[This forum post](http://goldendict.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2358) by [wissam](http://goldendict.org/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=4108) describes how to set up Google TTS with GoldenDict using the method described above:

> if u want to use Google tts in GD u can do that following these steps:
>
> 1. Edit -> Dictionaries -> Programs.
> 2. click on Add and choose "Audio" in type field .
> 3. in "Command Line" field copy and paste this command:
>
>    ```
>    bash -c "p=$(echo "%GDWORD%" |sed 's/ /+/g'); wget -q -U Mozilla -O - translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8\&q=$p\&tl=en\&client=tw-ob | mpg123 -"
>    ```
> 4. click ok
>
>    for languages other than english change tl=en in the command ,for
>      example fr for french or es for spanish

Now this is online TTS of course and not necessarily what you are looking for but you can use the same method to add any type of TTS software to GoldenDict (e.g. `espeak %GDWORD%` as the command line).

Check [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech) out for good TTS apps on Linux.

Comment: i did as you said why it doesn't work i copied and paste the command to the command line and the speaker showed up and when i click on it nothing happens what the problem?

Comment: @mohammed Yep, you're right. Not working for me, either. Strange thing is: It did work a few months ago when I first tried it out. An update might have broken it. Sorry :/

Comment: no problem sir just notify me if you found a solution, thanks.

Comment: @mohammed You can see my answer. It works fine.

Comment: change the command to this:

bash -c "p=$(echo "%GDWORD%" |sed 's/ /+/g'); wget -q -U Mozilla -O - translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en\&q=$p | mpg123 -"

also be sure mpg123 is installed.

Comment: change the command to this:     bash -c "p=$(echo "%GDWORD%" |sed 's/ /+/g'); wget -q -U Mozilla -O - https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8\&q=$p\&tl=en\&client=tw-ob | mpg123 -"

Comment: Don't forget to install mpg123. By default, it may be not there.

Answer (score 3):

```
bash -c "p=$(echo "%GDWORD%" |sed 's/ /+/g'); wget -q -U Mozilla -O - https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8\&q=$p\&tl=en\&client=tw-ob | mpg123 -"
```

this worked for me.

Make sure you have installed mpg123: `sudo apt install mpg123`

Comment: Your are my hero, God Bless You. Worked for me, WoW.

Answer (score 3):

### Google Text-To-Speech (TTS)

- install simple google tts like that: http://tuxdiary.com/2014/09/29/google-text-to-speech-tts-linux/
  or https://github.com/Glutanimate/simple-google-tts
- Edit -> Dictionaries -> Programs.
- click on Add and choose "Audio" in type field .
- in "Command Line" field copy and paste this command:

  simple_google_tts en "%GDWORD%"

Don't forget make a symlink for simple_google_tts to your PATH (e.g. ~/bin or /usr/local/bin) to make it easier to access.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1. Install [Crow Translate](https://crow-translate.github.io/)
2. In GoldenDict, add `crow -s en -u “%GDWORD%”` to the "Programs" tab. The type should be "Audio". See figure below.

[image]

You can change the language of the TTS by changing the part `-s en` to another code like `it` for italian, `fr` for french, etc. See Crow translate documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want native woman accent like google download from here (+500K words ~ 2GB):
https://github.com/yousefvand/pronunciations

Answer (score 1):

- Install translate-shell (https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell) with `sudo apt install translate-shell`
- Go to goldendict program section and use `bash trans -b -p :en  %GDWORD%` in the command section, type audio.

This will translate anything that you search to English and then speak the English translation. You can change the *en* in the code to say it in another language. **Internet conection is required to work propearly**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swift program.

Example:

```
padsp /opt/swift/bin/swift -p "speech/rate=150,voice/cache-size=240000,audio/deadair=100" -n Diane "%GDWORD%"
```

[image: fig]