# Is there a natural sounding text-to-speech package?

Tags: sound

This question was asked here, four years ago: [Natural Sounding Text to Speech?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech)

However, text-to-speech is something that's still improving and evolving fast, and all of the answers yield software that sounds tinny or unnatural. I know that no TTS will be perfect, but I'm positive there must be better solutions now in 2015.

The size of the package doesn't matter; it doesn't have to be lightweight, it can be bloated for all I care; I only care about the end result. It only has to be free and available for Ubuntu.

Comment: Is not a good idea to duplicate [Natural Sounding Text to Speech?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech), nor duplicate any question every some years. People still add new (and good) answers on that question.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [MaryTTS](http://mary.dfki.de/) for a while and I think it's (most likely) the best TTS engine for Ubuntu. It British and American English, German, French, Italian, Swedish, Russian, Turkish, and Telugu with more languages down the line.

It also offers the choice of [creating a new voice](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/HMMVoiceCreation), so you can tailor it to suit your needs.

Comment: I can't find any installation documentation (the docs are all about the architecture), and the online demo doesn't work...

Comment: You can download the install package from the MaryTTS website (http://mary.dfki.de/download/releasenotes-5.0.html) and follow the instructions from that page.

Comment: I somehow wasn't able to find that no matter where I looked. Thanks, I will try it out.

Comment: I see it at the link you provided but don't see how to make it work.  I want a cron job that will speak the time at the top of each hour.

Answer (score 0):

If Chrome Extension is ok - you can try [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com). I am the author so your feedback is welcome :)

Comment: doesnt work for me. Complains about internet connection problems although my wifi works perfectly

Comment: What is your current version? You can get in on `chrome://extensions/?id=eidcpcpmmfiolomceegcagooodnaplmp`