# Can you use the NVDA Voice Addons on Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, text-to-speech

https://vocalizer-nvda.com/downloads

There are a bunch of voice addons here, and I'd like to use them on Ubuntu/Linux to read text documents, in the way where I would give it a text document or a string of text, and it would generate an audio file I can play in rhythmbox.

Is there a way to do this? I don't mind using wine.

Comment: Haven't tried yet, so can't say much. I think if you love NVDA so much, then you might need run Windows in Virtualbox. Sorry, can't make a comment yet.

Comment: That is acceptable if it is contained enough, however, it is not that I love NVDA so much, but rather, that I want to use the voices here which are provided free of charge. They originate from Vocalizer 6.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, NVDA isn't listed in [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true). It means that untested on Wine yet.

But, you can try one of [this](https://sites.google.com/site/readtextextension/home/linux) for Linux.

Comment: Is it possible to get espeak or pico to use those voices provided?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

**SVOX pico2wave**
A very minimalistic TTS, a better sounding than espeak

[gSpeech](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/svox) is a simple Python, GTK+ front end for the command line application pico2wave from the GNU/Linux SVOX Pico implementation.

Also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech)

Comment: I know pico2wav... the sound quality is the best linux has, but it is still awful compared to the commercial solutions, and it annoyingly has an extremely low character limit.