# Are there any good text-to-speech plugins for firefox?

Tags: firefox-extensions, text-to-speech

Know any good TTS software for linux, preferrebly well integrated into firefox? Ideally it would work offline and don't require payment, but I'm willing to look at alternatives.

Comment: Have a look at this variety of choices: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Cainteoir software. It can be used offline by installing voices and Convert various types of documents (HTML, plain text, PDF, ePub, XHTML, XML etc) into speeches.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:msclrhd-gmail/cainteoir

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install cainteoir-gtk
```

Then you may install additional voices, e.g.:

```
 sudo apt-get install mbrola-us2
```

Look here for more info: [Hectikgeek page](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/07/text-to-speech-software-ubuntu-linux-cainteoir-tts/)

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Google™ Translator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-translator/) add-on for Firefox, as I don't know any good TTS software for Linux with natural voice. So this is on-line solution, you can mark text and than you get bubble where you can click to read a text. It also works on pdf files when you open them in Firefox. 
[image: Google Translator in use]

And most important the voice is natural, what is not case with existing Linux TTS. The best free TTS software for Linux is probably MeryTTS

Comment: MeryTTS (http://mary.dfki.de/) has very natural sound. Here is on-line demo (http://mary.dfki.de:59125/)