# Automatically end each command in terminal with a different message or sound

Tags: command-line, bash, sound

I installed [SVOX pico2wave](https://askubuntu.com/a/179922/869885) and created a script. 
Now when I enter:

```
speech "Hello world"
```

The computer text-to-voice engine says out loud "Hello world". Furthermore, I use in `.bashrc` the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` defined as:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="speech 'Command executed.'"
```

So the nice text-to-voice engine announces me loud that the command is executed, before returning the prompt in the terminal.

However, this gets boring after a while and I thought it would be really cool to end each command in terminal with the computer speaking a *different* line of text (think of the autopilot of Starship Enterprise).

So I created in .bashrc an array variable, with different messages:

```
array[0]="Shields at 90%"
array[1]="Engaging proton overdrive"
array[2]="Autopilot disengaged"
array[3]="Targetting solution available"
array[4]="Alert. Incoming missile."
array[5]="Deploying countermeasures."
array[6]="Firing torpedoes."
array[7]="Engaging auto-cannon."
array[8]="Severe damage on deck 17. Sealing off."
array[9]="Deploying repair droids to deck 17."
```

What I would like, is that **each** time I run a command in terminal, the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` to be updated and read a **different** random line in the array.

I presume I need a loop, but I didn't know how to make it.

I would be most grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: In the script in the linked answer, make sure you change the `-l=de-DE` to your local language like `-l=en-US`.

Comment: Thanks, indeed. This needs to be taken care of, but I had done it.

Comment: Yeah, that is just a comment in general.  Pretty cool idea here!  +1

Comment: Just curious - how can I install `speech` executable? Is it alias for `espeak`?

Comment: "speech" is a script. I followed the instructions in the link. I made a script called speech.sh, including the corrections indicated above by Terrance". I saved speech.sh in my ~/scripts folder. I changed file permissions to speech.sh to make it executable. I created a folder as follows: ~/scripts/bin and followed the instructions from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20054809, in order to add it to the PATH, so the script can be recognized as executable, no matter where I am.

Comment: Please do **not** write answers in the body of your question. If you want to share your "final solution" then *add it as a new answer to your own question*.

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you for your suggestion. I approved the change and proceeded according to the guidlines.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a script and save it somewhere which contains your lines and the logic to choose a random line from your array and calling `speech` command on that line:

```
array[0]="Shields at 90%"
array[1]="Engaging proton overdrive"
array[2]="Autopilot disengaged"
array[3]="Targetting solution available"
array[4]="Alert. Incoming missile."
array[5]="Deploying countermeasures."
array[6]="Firing torpedoes."
array[7]="Engaging auto-cannon."
array[8]="Severe damage on deck 17. Sealing off."
array[9]="Deploying repair droids to deck 17."

line=${array[$RANDOM % ${#array[@]}]}
speech "$line"
```

Then in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` set `PROMPT_COMMAND`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="bash $HOME/PATH/TO/myscript.sh"
```

Just replace the `speech` with `echo` to get a messge instead of the voice.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. It seems to work, except that it only renders the first word in the random line (eg. "Shields." or "Deploying..") not the entire line (eg. "Shields at 90%" or "Deploying repair droids on dek 17."

Comment: @RazTaz You're welcome ;)

Comment: Shouldn't `${array[$RANDOM % ${#array[@]}]}` be in double quotes?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's a good practice but not necessary here, run the script using `set -x` to see what I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 4):

**Later Edit Tutorial:**

Thanks to Ravexina's answer above, now the problem is solved and the solution works fantastically. I will give step-by-step instructions below, for the other people interested to make it work in Ubuntu 18.04

**1. Install SVOX pico2wave package:**

```
sudo apt-get install libttspico0 libttspico-utils libttspico-data libsox-fmt-mp3
```

**2. Create the speech script**

```
cd ~/scripts
gedit speech
```

and put this content inside, inserting the correct user in the path:

```
#!/bin/bash
pico2wave -l=en-US -w=/home/user/test.wav "$1"
aplay -q ~/test.wav
rm /home/user/test.wav
```

save and exit.

**3. Create the shell_speech.sh script as indicated by Ravexina above:**

```
gedit shell_speech
```

```
array[0]="Shields at 90%"
array[1]="Engaging proton overdrive"
array[2]="Autopilot disengaged"
array[3]="Targetting solution available"
array[4]="Alert. Incoming missile."
array[5]="Deploying countermeasures."
array[6]="Firing torpedoes."
array[7]="Engaging auto-cannon."
array[8]="Severe damage on deck 17. Sealing off."
array[9]="Deploying repair droids to deck 17."

line=${array[$RANDOM % ${#array[@]}]}
speech "$line"
```

save and exit.

**4. Make the scripts executable and add their directory to PATH so that they could be called from everywhere:**

```
chmod u+x ~/scripts/bin/speech
chmod u+x ~/scripts/bin/shell_speech
export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts
```

**5. Modify .bashrc**

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

add the following line:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="bash shell_speech"
```

save and close

*Note:* you can add as many new lines as you want in the array in `~/scripts/bin/shell_speech`

Comment: Since you've made the script executable and in the `PATH`, you don't need to include `bash` in your `PROMPT_COMMAND` and I would use single quotes in case you add other things later that will need to have deferred execution: `PROMPT_COMMAND='shell_speech'`

Comment: For security reasons it is better to write `/bin/bash` instead of a simple `bash`... (good practice just in case someone put another bash in your path before `/bin`...). I should even suggest you a [temp random file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181938/66388) in the `/tmp` directory instead that `test.wav` in your home... ps> give it a look to [fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)).

Comment: @Hastur think for a minute under what circumstances your assumption can become true (i.e "someone put another bash in your path before /bin"). This is possible only if someone either has physical access to your computer and/or has already escalated privileges. Under both circumstances, your solution is not fixing the problem.

Comment: @RazTaz World is full of colors, not just __black__ and _white_! :-). Unfortunately there are a lot of ways to have partial privileges on a system, and to use only `bash` is a way to obtain more. Links, script, write permission on open directories, shared ones... Moreover --  you may miss it -- scripts can survive to their first aim or owner... and you (or someone else) can use them after enough time that you do not remember all the commands written inside (we do for that), under different conditions. To put `\bin\bash` with the explicit path _is_ a good practice. To avoid to do it... a risk.