# Frontend for TTS - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Are there any frontend text to speech for Ubuntu 20.04 ?
Gespeaker isn't supported anymore.
Also pdf reader Ocular can't read aloud because Jovie is not supported.

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech) related question, _Natural Sounding Text to Speech?_

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer for a local app, but here is a web-based site that might serve as a work around until someone else chimes in with a better answer:

https://ttsreader.com/

Warning: it is not an open-source service, and is supported by advertisements