How to use Google's gTTs as Ubuntu's default speech dispatcher?
The default speech dispatcher in Ubuntu is somewhat robot-like. It is possible to change it using Pied.
Instead, how to make Google's text to speech the default TTS engine for Ubuntu?
This answer shows how to narrate a particular word with gTTs, but I want it to replace the system's speech dispenser.

Not a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/53896/natural-sounding-text-to-speech, because it does not show how to use gTTs as the default TTS engine.
