# Simple sound playback script

Tags: command-line, sound, scripts, playback

My laptop went down a few days ago and I lost my short sound script.  I thought someone here could help me rebuild it.  It was something like this:

Better post:  if sound prog were "pback" the command would be

```
pback file[s]

#!
FILE=$1;

cat FILE | [forgotten command]

#End
```

Can anybody help me with the command?

Comment: I wrote an answer presenting `espeak-ng` here just to realize this is a duplicate, so I deleted my answer and posted it [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164515/507051) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `festival`

> --tts
>   Synthesize text in files as speech no files means read from stdin (implies no interaction by default)

```
echo "I'm sorry Dave, I can't do that." | festival --tts
```

Comment: YES!  I just got a new k'board; fun, fun.  May the devil not know you're dead for a few hours [or years] after you've cashed in!